# Why won't my images display in html email?

Tags: php, email

I have a script for sending HTML email messages which works fine for text and html tags but I cannot figure out why my images wont display.

```
function sendHtmlEmail($email, $content, $message_content){
    $to = "$email";
    $subject = "AeroBLOG - $content";

    $message = "
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>$subject</TITLE>
        <META http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <STYLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
           $message_content
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
    ";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <do-not-reply@aeroblog.tk>' . "\r\n";

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){return true;}else{return false;}
}
```

call to function:

```
$message="<A href=\"http://aeroblog.tk/\"><IMG src=\"http://aeroblog.tk/img/VerificationEmail.png\" alt=\"copy & paste this link into your browsers navigation bar: http://.........\" width=\"1024px\" height=\"768px\"></A>";

sendHtmlMail("myemail@example.com","Subject",$message);
```

Here is the complete email which is returned including headers:

```
Delivered-To: oneal.michaels@gmail.com
Received: by 10.182.154.35 with SMTP id vl3csp1831038obb;
        Sun, 6 Dec 2015 16:26:01 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.13.213.14 with SMTP id x14mr19939281ywd.229.1449447961510;
        Sun, 06 Dec 2015 16:26:01 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <a6602671@srv10.000webhost.com>
Received: from postlady.000webhost.com (smtp5.000webhost.com. [31.170.163.248])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id j63si14327386ywf.69.2015.12.06.16.26.01
        for <oneal.michaels@gmail.com>;
        Sun, 06 Dec 2015 16:26:01 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of a6602671@srv10.000webhost.com designates 31.170.163.248 as permitted sender) client-ip=31.170.163.248;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of a6602671@srv10.000webhost.com designates 31.170.163.248 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=a6602671@srv10.000webhost.com
Received: by postlady.000webhost.com ([000webhost.com Mail Server], from userid 99)
    id 59C5B602FC; Mon,  7 Dec 2015 00:26:01 +0000 (UTC)
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.2 (2011-06-06) on
    postlady.000webhost.com
X-Spam-Level: ****
X-Spam-Status: No, score=4.6 required=7.0 tests=BODY_URI_ONLY,
    HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08,HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_02,HTML_MESSAGE,HTML_SHORT_LINK_IMG_1,
    MIME_HTML_ONLY,TVD_RCVD_SPACE_BRACKET,T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD autolearn=disabled
    version=3.3.2
Received: from srv10.000webhost.com (srv10.000webhost.com [31.170.160.74])
    by postlady.000webhost.com ([000webhost.com Mail Server]) with ESMTP id 9924B602FB
    for <oneal.michaels@gmail.com>; Mon,  7 Dec 2015 00:25:26 +0000 (UTC)
Received: by srv10.000webhost.com (Postfix, from userid 6602671)
    id 929B018B5C7; Sun,  6 Dec 2015 19:25:26 -0500 (EST)
To: oneal.michaels@gmail.com
Subject: AeroBLOG - Verification Email: Welcome, MikeIsMyName
X-PHP-Script: aeroblog.tk/sendVerificationEmail.php for 172.73.244.114
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8
From: <do-not-reply@aeroblog.tk>
Message-Id: <20151207002526.929B018B5C7@srv10.000webhost.com>
Date: Sun,  6 Dec 2015 19:25:26 -0500 (EST)


    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>AeroBLOG - Verification Email: Welcome, MikeIsMyName</TITLE>
        <META http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <STYLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <A href="http://aeroblog.tk/"><IMG src="http://aeroblog.tk/img/VerificationEmail.png" alt="copy & paste this link into your browsers navigation bar: http://........." width="1024px" height="768px"></A>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: Likes like your image is sent wit your email. Do you realize that not every email provider allows the users to download images? Most of them will not allow it.

Comment: why was this tagged as javascript and jquery?

Comment: oops, I didn't realize it when I was filling in tags. I use jQuery to call the mail script so I put it in there without thinking..[fixing that]

Answer (score 0):

Some e-mail servers blocks images contents from some e-mails. Did you try looking at the "source code" of the e-mail? In gmail you can find it by clicking in Show Original Message. Another thing that can be happening is that the client is not able to access the image file in your website, or the image link is incorrect.

If you still have trouble with this, I recommend using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send your e-mails. It's really easy to use and has a lot of functions, such as SSL and TLS or Attachments in e-mails.

Comment: I am using GMail which supports images, but my webhost doesn't allow hot-linking, could that be the problem? I'm not 100% sure as to what the definition of hot-linking is...

Comment: @MichaelO'Neal: Yes, disabled hotlinking can be problem, because hosted images may only be opened in the context of the hosted website. Any email client will be outside of that context.

Comment: @MichaelO'Neal I think you can find a free image hosting on the web. So you can upload your images there to use on your e-mails.